# Vim7.4でタブ幅の設定が反映されない

Tags: vim

Vim7.4でタブ幅の設定が反映されません。タブ(\t)がスペース4つ分で表示されるべきなのですが、8つ分で表示されてしまいます。

下のようにvimrcに設定しているのでtabキーを押すとスペース4つが入力され、
タブ(\t)の表示もスペース4つ分の幅になるはずだと思うのですが、
(\t)がスペース8つ分で表示されてしまいます。

システムに付属するvim7.3はきちんと表示されるのですが、Homebrewでインストールしたvim7.4ではきちんと表示されません。

```
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

すべてのファイルでそうなりますか？
新しいvimでは、pythonなどの一部ファイル形式でタブを8スペースと表示します。(設定が上書きされます)

http://blog.kcrt.net/2014/04/29/102937 をご参照下さい。

Comment: pythonのファイルでの現象だったのですが、標準のpythonの設定をスペース4つ分に変える方法はありますか？

Comment: 標準の設定を変えることで対応することもできますが、その場合はbrew updateしてしまうとまた設定が戻ることになります。タブ文字を使わないのが一番ですが、設定で対応するなら、.vimrcに`autocmd FileType python setlocal tabstop=4`と書けば良いです。

Answer (score 3):

考えられるのは大きく分けて2つで、

1. vimrc がうまく読み込まれていない
2. 他の部分で上書きされている

です。7.3 で動いてるということなので、1 の可能性は低そうです。
他の部分で上書きされているかどうかは、

```
:verbose set tabstop?
```

とすることで、現在の設定値と、その設定を最後に行ったファイルが表示できるので、これで現在の設定値が 4 になっていなければ、設定を上書きした犯人がわかるかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

Homebrewでvimをインストールした場合、macvimをインストールする必要があるようです。

[Installing Vim with homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694327/installing-vim-with-homebrew)

> after installing vim with homebrew you should install macvim